# "Failed to fetch region" (new Error("NO_RESULT", "resource://gre/modules/Region.jsm", 376)) error using GeckoDriver and Firefox through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

This code works on an English Windows username, but does not on a non-english username

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver  # Import from seleniumwire
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
options = FirefoxOptions()

firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(r'D:\yt\tempProfile')
url = "https://www.google.com/"
try:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_profile,options=options)
    print("path=",str(driver.firefox_profile.path))
    driver.get(url)    
finally:
    if 'driver'  in locals():
        driver.quit()
    else:
        print("driver is none")
```

I think having a non-english Windows username creates a problem with running geckodriver .

geckodriver.log:

```
1607996979444   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:50416
1607996984556   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "--marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\88D7~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile64HlEP"
1607996985346   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 50424
1607996985603   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
1607996985604   Marionette  INFO    Proxy settings initialised: {"proxyType":"manual","httpProxy":"127.0.0.1:50414","noProxy":[],"sslProxy":"127.0.0.1:50414"}
1607996986131   Marionette  INFO    Stopped listening on port 50424
console.error: Region.jsm: "Error fetching region" (new TypeError("NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.", ""))
console.error: Region.jsm: "Failed to fetch region" (new Error("NO_RESULT", "resource://gre/modules/Region.jsm", 376))

###!!! [Child][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost


###!!! [Child][MessageChannel::SendAndWait] Error: Channel error: cannot send/recv
```

its trying to run a profile from temp folder inside appdata.

Is there a way to tell geckodriver to use a different temp folder?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
console.error: Region.jsm: "Error fetching region" (new TypeError("NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.", ""))
console.error: Region.jsm: "Failed to fetch region" (new Error("NO_RESULT", "resource://gre/modules/Region.jsm", 376))
```

...implies that the *Firefox* was unable to trigger the downloading of region maps within the new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Firefox Browser* session as you are handling a *non-english* username.

---

### Trigger download of map

[**Trigger download of map**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1627550) was a known issue with [mozilla](/questions/tagged/mozilla) which got addressed through [changeset](https://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-release/rev/bdb066a162676f51b179daa3c95e7b077c888276) and should be available with **Firefox 79** with the *Mozilla Preference* enabled.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to current levels [Version 3.141](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *GeckoDriver* is upgraded to [GeckoDriver v0.28.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0) level.
- *Firefox* is upgraded to current *Firefox v84.0* levels.